# How to hide console application window with windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-4.5, windows-task-scheduler

I've written a small console app that moves backed up databases from one machine to another location via email.

How this works, the machine that the SQL server is on I've got a job created with-in SQL that backs up specific databases to a volume storage that is with-in the same machine but not on the same volume as the Server 2008rC operating system is on.

So, every night about 1am the job runs and backs up specific databases to a volume that I'm only using to back up database specific items.
Now, every night about 2am I'm running a windows task that invokes my console application, this console application is the code below an is very simple. All it does is retrieves the databases, zips them all up into one zip file and then emails the backed up databases to a specific email, and from that point the databases get stored at various locations so that I've got a little redundancy.

Here is my question(s).

1.) What is the minimum amount of permissions that I should set on the Root folder that the backed up databases are being stored in so that the windows task scheduler will be able to invoke my console app, and in turn my console app does read, write, and deletes. I would like the minimum amount of permissions set.

2.) How to I run the console app by hiding the console window so that if an admin is logged on they do not see that window when the console app is invoked via that windows task scheduler. Now, I've been told that I can set my application to a windows forms from a console app and this will fix my window issues, but my question to that is does this mean that every day at 2am this will create a new window and the windows stay active? In other words I need to run this console app, the console app needs to do what it's task is set to do, and I need the console app to complete die out and not be running any longer until 24 hours later at 2am.

**Here is all the code that creates the zip file, emails the zip file, and the deletes the zip file.
What direction should I take here?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace SendDatabaseMail
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                string supportEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["supportemail"],
                       dataFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["datafolder"],
                       zippedFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["zippedfolder"],
                       zippedfilename = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["zippedfilename"],
                       smtpServer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpserver"],
                       smtpPort = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpport"],
                       mailSubject = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailsubject"],
                       mailBody = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailbody"],
                       mailPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailpassword"],
                       databasesRepository = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databasesrepository"];


                string repositoryPath = databasesRepository + "/" + dataFolder,
                       zipPath = databasesRepository + "/" + zippedFolder;

                if (Directory.GetFiles(repositoryPath).Length > 0)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(supportEmail), new MailAddress(supportEmail)))
                        {
                            mm.Subject = mailSubject;
                            mm.Body = mailBody;

                            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(repositoryPath, zipPath + "/" + zippedfilename);

                            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(zipPath + "/" + zippedfilename));

                            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, short.Parse(smtpPort)))
                            {
                                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(supportEmail, mailPassword);
                                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                                smtp.Send(mm);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }

                    if (File.Exists(zipPath + "/" + zippedfilename))
                    {
                        File.Delete(zipPath + "/" + zippedfilename);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You really should use something like SSIS and SQL Server Agent to do this.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is after 3 years,

In the Visual Studio, in the project Properties,

Select the output type to **Windows Application**